# Unable to figure out lua table inheritence

Tags: lua

Hope someone can make sense of what I'm attempting to figure out, Just don't seem to understand Lua enough to achieve this.

```
--[[
    tbl.a.test("moo") returns "Table A moo appears"
    tbl.b.test("moo") returns "moo appears"
]]
tbl = {
    a = { ID = "Table A" },
    b = {
        test = function(...) print(... .. " appears") end,
    }, 
}
tbl.a__index = function(self, ...) tbl.b[self](tbl.a.ID .. ...) end
```

What I'm attempting to do is I could create several tables a, c, d, e and not have to copy test to each one. When `tbl.a.test`, `tbl.c.test`, `tbl.d.test` is used, It'll retrieve the `tbl.a.ID` var, then call `tbl.b.test(ID, "moo")`

So far all I'm finding out is it's not able to find .test on anything other than tbl.b

** EDIT **
Thank's to support so far the code is now;

```
tbl = {
    a = { ID = "Table A " },
    b = { test = function(...) local id, rest = ... print(id .. ": " .. rest)     end },
}
setmetatable(tbl.a, {__index=function(self, k, ...) local rest = ... return     tbl.b[k](tbl.a.ID, rest) end})
```

However, the ... is not being progressed for some odd reason :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're missing a period between `tbl.a` and `__index`.
- `__index` needs to be on `a`'s metatable, not the table itself.
- You don't return anything from your `__index` function
- `self` in the `__index` function is the table being indexed, not the key (which is the second argument)

This should work:

```
setmetatable(tbl.a, {__index=function(self, k) return tbl.b[k](tbl.a.ID) end})
```

Comment: Thank you Colonel Thirty Two, This has worked to passing on the ID, However it's unable to pass on "moo", I modified the line to;

    setmetatable(tbl.a, {__index=function(self, k, rest) tbl.b[k](tbl.a.ID, rest) end})

However it doesn't seem to receive it on tbl.b.test, Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @CrazyCactuaR `tbl.a.test("moo")` does three separate steps. It first retrieves `a` from `tbl`, which happens normally. It then retrieves `test` from the value retrieved from the previous step, which is where `__index` is called (with `tbl.a` as `self` and `"test"` as `k`) and returns a value to use. It then calls the value retrieved from the previous step.

Comment: Would that mean I'm actually unable to pass a varible to the function only indirectly retrieve what it returns?

Comment: It just means that `__index` doesn't know anything about what you're using the value you're indexing for. You can however return a closure: `__index = function(self,k) return function(...) return tbl.b[k](tbl.a.ID, ...) end end`

Comment: woohoo! That's exactly what I was attempting to learn, a very big thank you and someday I may understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- [Sub]Class creation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function newclass(new_obj,old_obj)
  old_obj = old_obj or {}               --use passed-in object (if any)
  new_obj = new_obj or {}
  assert(type(new_obj) == 'table','New Object/Class is not a table')
  assert(type(old_obj) == 'table','Old Object/Class is not a table')
  old_obj.__index = old_obj             --store __index in parent object (optimization)
  return setmetatable(new_obj,old_obj)  --create 'new_obj' inheriting 'old_obj'
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

prototype = {
  test = function(self,s) print('Table ' .. self.id .. ' ' .. s .. ' appears') end
}

tbl = {}

tbl.a = newclass({id = 'A'},prototype)
tbl.b = newclass({id = 'B'},prototype)

tbl.a:test('moo')
tbl.b:test('moo')
```

The distinction between class and object in Lua is only theoretical.  In practice they are implemented exactly the same way.

Anytime you need to do inheritance, you can use my general-purpose newclass() function to either create a new class/object, or inherit from an existing one.

Any common code & data you would like to have passed on should go into the 'prototype' table (whatever you'd like to call it for each case).

Also, you seem to forget to use the method calling syntax (that uses a colon instead of a dot) when calling methods.  Without it, the self parameter is not automatically recognized.