# function as parameter lua

Tags: function, parameters, lua

following problem is mine:

i want to have a function that create a new object in lua, but it should be possible to extend it.

```
function Class(table)
local a = {}
local t = {create = _create, __newindex = function(o,k,v) 
            if k == "create" then
              --getmetatable(o).create = function()
                --_create(o) 
                --v()
              --end
              -- or just create(v.params)
            else
              rawset(o,k,v)
            end
          end,
}

setmetatable(a,t)
t.__index = t
end

function _create(o,...)
return newTable
end

ele = Class:create()
function Class:create( n )
    self.name = n
end
ele2 = Class:create("bbbb")
```

now the ele2 is without a name, but it schould be create a new object with the given string as name.

can i get the parameter of given value(type function) from newindex or can i execute the value?

Comment: What is `a`? What is `newTable`? Have you given functions metatables? (How does `Class:create` work when `Class` is a function?)

Comment: Have a look at my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128069/unable-to-figure-out-lua-table-inheritence

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'm not sure about.  As Etan said, what is `newTable` and why are you trying to set `create` as a function of `Class` when `Class` is a function?

If you're looking for a way to init an instance of a class when it is created, you can do something like this:

```
function Class()
    local class = {}
    class.__index = class 
    return setmetatable(class, {__call = function(...)
        local instance = setmetatable({}, class)
        if instance.init then 
            instance:init(select(2, ...))
        end 
        return instance
    end}) 
end

--now an example:

Dog = Class()

function Dog:init(name)
    self.name = name 
end

function Dog:bark()
    print(string.format("%s barked!", self.name))
end

local pedro = Dog("Pedro")
pedro:bark() --> pedro barked!
```